# How to automate a script to insert data into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an excel file which has a column and the data in the column is :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Id1, Id2, Id3) 
VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

Can someone please let me know how can i automate this through SSIS so the insert statement directly loads data into the table?

I can create an SSIS package to load this excel file into a table however I need the column to execute and insert data into Test table.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be storing a SQL script in the column, you should just be storing the values. In this case cells A1:C1 should value the value `ID1`, `ID2`, and `ID3` respectively, and cells A2:C2 should have the values `1`,`2`, and `3` respectively. Then importing the data is trivial with an Excel Source.

Comment: Why complicate things? If your "script" (that single insert statement) is all you have, just put it in script file where you can run it against any database at any time using a variety of tools. This seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you want to automate a SQL script, *powershell* is a popular tool for such tasks; loading data from Excel is easy but it should be *just data*, what would happen of someone edited the excel file and changed the content of the cell to 'drop table....' or worse?

Comment: Would it be accurate to restate the problem as: Within the context of an SSIS Package, I need to read a specific cell in an Excel file as a string. I then need to use that string as a query against a database?

Comment: There are so many different ways to accomplish this, however, do you think letting some Excel user pass a query to be blindly run against a production server is a good idea?

Comment: Anyway... Use Exec SQL Task to read the one cell you need 
 select * from [SheetName$]:$C$2 and store result into variable. Use variable in another exec sql. Good Luck. This is bound to not end well.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you already have a complete SSIS package with connection to excel and connection to database and finally also with transformation in pipeline (grab data from source, push it into destination).

There are different ways how to execute SSIS package from within SQL Server (exec as bat or cmd), but I suggest you official one.

You can find complete step by step tutorial how to deploy SSIS to SQL Server here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15

Basically, right click in the Visual studio on the project and click deploy... Follow steps...

Take a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15#to-deploy-and-execute-a-package-using-stored-procedures
There is step by step tutorial how to run your SSIS package from Stored Procedure.

Now you have to decide how to automatize run of Stored procedure itself. Also here you have so many approaches, for example your own timer implementation from outside of SQL Server, or using Windows Task Scheduler.

As I don't really know your environment, Il suggest you easy way to create a scheduled Job with SQL Server Agent (it have to be installed at your SQL Server instance).

step by step tutorial is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hello Matej, Thanks a lot for the reply. Sorry if i am not clear my question is one of the column in excel file has a SQL Insert statement. How do i run that statement so the data gets inserted? My SSIS package will basically get that column and input into a table however i want that insert statement from the excel column to be executed and the data to be loaded into the table

Comment: Hello John, I think I understand it now. There are also several options in SSIS but also without SSIS. 1. So, do exactly what I told you in my answer + split aproach to 2 steps. Insert also column that contains your insert statements. For example you can also create different "staging table" for those data. Then create different stored procedure that will be executed also from Job after the first one. You can use then sp_executesql from SQL SERVER and just set sql comand and execute it inside your SP... like @_sqlcmd varchar(255) = select cmd from stagingTable execute sp_executesql @_sqlcmd

Comment: But  I have to tell you also that there is something weird that you have to read sql statements from excel cell... Its always better to store data properly and do SSIS pipeline correctly.

Comment: Hello Matej, I understand the requirement is weird but i have to live with it for now. So, i created a staging table dbo.stg which has a column named "Script" and in that column i have the insert statement. Can you please help me with the SP on  how can i split the "Script" column to load that insert into 3 different columns on dbo.test such as ID1,ID2,ID3

Comment: For example(if your table contains multiple rows, do it in cycle for example (cursor or while)): declare @_sqlcommand varchar(255) = (select Script from dbo.stg) exec sp_executesql @_sqlcommand ... Whole command is in cell Script... Ofc, use more than varchar(255) if command is longer

Comment: Sorry to bother you Matej, i am a new SQL developer and not much familiar with the cursors. Below is my Script column code :
Insert into dbo.test(ID1,ID2,ID3)Values(1,2,3)
Insert into dbo.test(ID1,ID2,ID3)Values(4,5,6)
Can you please help me with the sample code for cursor or while loop on how can i loop my script column to load into the test table and load the values into ID1,ID2,ID3

Comment: DECLARE @_sqlcommand varchar(511)

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Script from dbo.stg 
  
OPEN my_cursor;  
  
-- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
INTO  @_sqlcommand;
  
-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    exec sp_executesql @_sqlcommand
 
   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  
   FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
   INTO  @_sqlcommand   ;
END  
  
CLOSE my_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE my_cursor;

Comment: Thanks a lot Matej, It works.